# Xamarin Themes Switch dark and light

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, themes, resourcedictionary

I updated to Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Forms.Pages V2.3.5.233-pre1 and my dynamic theme changes quit working on current screen.  Previously it would change the screen I'm on when I change it and any open screen.  Now it seems to require me to close any open screen and reopen it.  I'm not sure how to refresh the screens, as that's really not a desired option.

Here is how I change the themes.  Any advice would be helpful.  If I go back to previous version, it works fine, but then I lose new features I needed.

I'm just using the dark and light themes given
I have a simple picker to select them.

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Label Text="Theme"  HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
    <Picker SelectedIndex="{Binding Theme,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Picker.Items>
            <x:String>Light</x:String>
            <x:String>Dark</x:String>
        </Picker.Items>
    </Picker>
    </StackLayout>
```

I change it with the following by binding picker to Theme below:

```
      public int Theme
        {
            get { return _theme; }
            set
            {
                _theme = value;
                App.SetTheme = (MySettings.Theme)value;
            }
        }
```

in App:

```
            public static MySettings.Theme SetTheme {
            set
            {
                if (value == MySettings.Theme.Light)
                {
                    App.Current.Resources = new ResourceDictionaryLight();
                }
                else if (value == MySettings.Theme.Dark)
                {
                    App.Current.Resources = new ResourceDictionaryDark();
                }
            }
        }
```

The ResourceDictionaryLight xaml like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                 x:Class="ChurchApp.ResourceDictionaryLight" 
                 MergedWith="light:LightThemeResources"
                 xmlns:light="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Themes;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Light">
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Feels like a bug (either in old or new) since it changed how it worked without me changing any code.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Xamarin.Forms 4.7, `AppThemeBinding` was introduced which makes theme management very easy for user as it is built-in inside the framework.

Here is an example on ow to define your attributes in both Light and Dark theme:

```
<Label Text="Hellow World" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=White, Light=Black}"/>
```

It is not the main goal but note that you are not limited to colors you can define the values for any attributes that will be set for Light and for Dark theme.
It may not be a practical example but just for demo:

```
<Label Text="Hellow World" FontSize={AppThemeBinding Dark=12, Light=15} TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=White, Light=Black}"/>
```

More important you can select and change the Theme by setting the property `App.Current.UserAppTheme` (wherever in your app and without restart or closing any page)
to either:

- Dark: `OSAppTheme.Dark`.
- Light: `OSAppTheme.Light`.
- Unspecified:  `OSAppTheme.Unspecified`. If Android version supports dark theme ([Android 10 (API level 29) and higher](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme)), then your app will follow Android current selected theme when this property is set like so.

#### Helpful documentation

1. [Microsoft Blog: App Themes for Xamarin.Forms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/app-themes-xamarin-forms/).
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes.
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/consuming#appthemebinding-markup-extension

Comment: While this is helpful information and valuable, doesn't really answer the question of why it wont dynmically change in an app.  I still find I have to close the app and reopen it for the  theme to be implemented.  Do you have an example of this working in a project where it will change while the app is functioning?   Rather than having to specify in each item the color for dark and light, the resourcedictionary gives a one place for all controls to be affected without going through every control, yet when you change it, for me it doesn't live update the app.  Requires a close and open.  Thks

Comment: Just to be clear the theme that doesn't change dynamically, the theme you have implemented by your own or you have tried the built-in `AppThemeBinding` (simply switch theme in one line of code without restarting) and it is not working for you? Which version of Xamarin.Forms are you using?

Comment: I would need to implement the changes you describe.  What I'm saying is I still am using ResourceDictionary's currently one for light and one for dark, and when I change them, the app requires a restart to implement the change.  One day it worked and changed right away, and the next it didn't which is why I posted this originally.    If I implement what you've described, is that not required?  Thanks.  I have not used AppThemeBinding yet.  I'm currently using 4.6.0.726 xamarin.forms.

Comment: It will need some work at the beginning since you are migrating from your own implementation to a whole new implementation but once you define your basic requirement for theme it is very easy to manage/customize, this is the main advantage.

Comment: I did upvote it.  I haven't had time to test it though.

Comment: Just checking in I thought you forget about implementation or drop it for another solution, no worries :)